# Twilio autopilot voice recognition language

Tags: twilio

I am programming an IVR with autopilot.Looking to the queries of my autopilot simulator, I could find that the autopilot always tries to recognize the words and speech in English vocuabulary.
My problem is that I need the recognition of the voice be made in other language(spanish), is there any way to change this?
I will be so grateful if you can help me with that.

In this screenshot you can see the queries, actually I am speaking in spanish but always it tries to find the most similar word or words of english vocabulary

[autopilot queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQrUW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Autopilot today supports English only https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/languages.